# Access latest value of state in aws amplify subscriptions react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-hooks, aws-amplify, graphql-subscriptions

I have a useEffect hook with a subscription listener using aws-amplify like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
        todoUpdatedSubs.subscribe({
          next: (status: SubscriptionStatus<OnTodoUpdatedSubscription>) => {
            setIsTaskUpdated(true);
            // when mutation will run the next will trigger
            console.log("New Updated SUBSCRIPTION ==> ", status);
            if (!status.value.data.onTodoUpdated.success)
              return console.log("error", status);
    
            const newArr = [...todos];
            console.log("Prev todos", todos);
            const { id, todo, isCompleted } = status.value.data.onTodoUpdated;
            newArr[editingIndex] = { id, todo, isCompleted };
            setTodos(newArr);
          },
        });}, [])
```

The problem is that the next function in useEffect does not have the latest value of `todo` state because the useEffect only ran on mount. If I do something like this, multiple listeners are mounted:

```
useEffect(() => {
        todoUpdatedSubs.subscribe({
          next: (status: SubscriptionStatus<OnTodoUpdatedSubscription>) => {
            setIsTaskUpdated(true);
            // when mutation will run the next will trigger
            console.log("New Updated SUBSCRIPTION ==> ", status);
            if (!status.value.data.onTodoUpdated.success)
              return console.log("error", status);
    
            const newArr = [...todos];
            console.log("Prev todos", todos);
            const { id, todo, isCompleted } = status.value.data.onTodoUpdated;
            newArr[editingIndex] = { id, todo, isCompleted };
            setTodos(newArr);
          },
        });}, [todos])
```

How can I get the latest value of state in the listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) option of the `useState` hook. When setting the state using a callback, the callback is called with the previous values. This saves you the need to define `todos` as a dependency of the `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  todoUpdatedSubs.subscribe({
    next: (status: SubscriptionStatus<OnTodoUpdatedSubscription>) => {
      setIsTaskUpdated(true);
      // when mutation will run the next will trigger
      console.log("New Updated SUBSCRIPTION ==> ", status);
      if (!status.value.data.onTodoUpdated.success)
        return console.log("error", status);
        
      setTodos(todos => {
        const newArr = [...todos];
        const { id, todo, isCompleted } = status.value.data.onTodoUpdated;
        newArr[editingIndex] = { id, todo, isCompleted };
        
        return newArr;
      });
    },
});}, [])
```

If you need to use the updated `todos` value inside `useEffect`, but not when updating the state, you can use `useRef` instead.

In your case I would use the functional updates option, but I'm adding this as an example:

```
const todosRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  todosRef.current = todos;
});

useEffect(() => {
  todoUpdatedSubs.subscribe({
    next: (status: SubscriptionStatus<OnTodoUpdatedSubscription>) => {
      setIsTaskUpdated(true);
      // when mutation will run the next will trigger
      console.log("New Updated SUBSCRIPTION ==> ", status);
      if (!status.value.data.onTodoUpdated.success)
        return console.log("error", status);
        
      const newArr = [...todosRef.current];
      const { id, todo, isCompleted } = status.value.data.onTodoUpdated;
      newArr[editingIndex] = { id, todo, isCompleted };
      setTodos(newArr);
    },
});}, [])
```

Comment: Okay let me check.

Comment: I don't know why but this method is not rerendering the list

Comment: Add a `console.log(todos)` to the body of the component after the relevant `useState()` (not inside `useEffect()`) .

Comment: I have tried a different approach which worked, basically, I set a new state that holds the updated todo values and a useEffect with that state as dep which modifies the todo list. Can you tell me if this is the correct approach?

Comment: Nope. The correct approach is the callback for setting the state. I've added another approach that uses ref. Using another state is redundant. However, if it works for you...

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: It took me almost a day to figure out this. Thanks